# Sort list of ints by the first digit of each int

Tags: python, loops, sorting

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a list of integers by the first digit in each int, (and if the same, move to the next digit, etc.)

I'm sure I can just loop through, (although I've been having issues because it seems like I need to make my list a list of strings in order to grab the first digit and this just hasn't been working out for me), but I'd like to know if there is a way to do this easily with the `sorted()` method.

EX:

```
myList = [34254, 2343, 49, 595, 323]
```

My desired result:

```
sortedList = [2343, 323, 34254, 49, 595]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort with a key of strings and you'll get ASCIIbetical sorting.

```
>>> myList = [34254, 2343, 49, 595, 323]
>>> sorted(myList, key=str)
[2343, 323, 34254, 49, 595]
```

Comment: or sorted(mylist, cmp = lambda x, y: str(x) > str(y) ) ?

Comment: Thanks TigerhawkT3 and @Jack Wu!  Those are both versions of what I'm looking for!